# html - Difference between these two tags?

Tags: html, syntax

What is the difference between `<element></element>` and `<element />`? I've been reading some HTML tutorials, and some use

`<img src="foo.png" alt="foo" />`

while others use

`<img src="bar.png" alt="bar"></img>`

What is the difference? When I try both, it doesn't seem to affect anything. Now, I'm just going to make a wild guess and say that this:

`<img src="bar.png" alt="bar"> is if you want to put something in between? </img>`

Can anyone confirm my guess and/or tell me what the difference is?

Comment: `<img src="bar.png" alt="bar"></img>` is invalid.

Comment: Image tag is a self closing tag in HTML, so this one is valid.
<img src="foo.png" alt="foo" />

Comment: It is? Huh, guess my notepad is bugged out then... but how come some tags don't requires that `</end tag>`?

Comment: Think of it this way: anything you put between the opening and closing tags is shown as text on the page. Some tags like for images don't need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
<img src="bar.png" alt="bar"> is if you want to put something in between? </img>
```

is not correct but I can understand what you mean to ask.

The ones of the form `<element />` are called **self-closing** tags.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/2534513

Answer (score 2):

A **void** tag requires no end tag, and in fact, *must not* specify an end tag (and thus, cannot have any content), as per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). The `<img>` tag is one of those void tags. Thus, if you run the following code through [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), you'll get an error on line 10: `Stray end tag img.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <img src="#" alt="">
            <img src="#" alt="" />
            <img src="#" alt=""></img>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are specifically 3 kinds of tags in HTML. Each standard tag is documented as of which type it should be (I say *should* because most browsers allow for tags with the wrong type).

- **Void tags**: Are composed only by the start tag, with no closing. `<x>` Examples:

  ```
  <br>
  <hr>
  ```
- **Self-closing tags**: Are start tags with the closing portion at the end. `<x />` Examples:

  ```
  <script />
  <style />
  <img />
  ```
- **Closing tags**: Are the common start-content-end tags. `<x> ... </x>` Examples:

  ```
  <div> ... </div>
  <a> ... </a>
  <em> ... </em>
  ```

---

If you want maximum theoretical vaildity on your HTML, this is super important, but in practice, most browsers treat a closing tag with no content as equivalent to self-closing and void tags. This means that albeit **invalid**, things like this will work:

```
<img src="a.png"></img>
<br />
```

## BUT!

You should never do this:

```
<div> blablabla
```

Closing tags must have a corresponding close otherwise you can mess up the markup pretty heavily.

If you stick to the standard, there will be no surprises.